# how can I visual a dense graph obviously in networkx python package?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-visualization

I have a large, dense directed graph in python, made with the [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) package. How can I improve the clarity of the graph image?

The following image shows my graph.
[image]

Comment: you need to provide more detail about your specific dataset otherwise this question is far too broad. A starting point might be to look at [Weighted Graphs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_weighted_graph.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-drawing-plot-weighted-graph-py)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can recommend you several ways to improve your graph visualization depending on its size.

---

If you want to visualize a large graph (>1000 nodes), you can read some tricks in [my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57697749/11227781). In your case I recommend you to import the graph to a large vector picture:

> ```
> import networkx as nx 
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
> fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40, 40)) 
> G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(300, 0.02, seed=1337) 
> nx.draw(G, node_size=30) 
> plt.axis('equal') 
> plt.show() 
> fig.savefig('waka.svg')
> ```

---

If you have relatively small graph (<1000 nodes), you can play with graph layouts.

The most suitable layout for your kind of graph is the default [spring_layout](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html#networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout). It has `k` argument that set the optimal distance between nodes. Here is the example:

**Default k value**

```
import networkx as nx
import random
random.seed(1234)
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(30, 0.4, seed=1337)
for i in range(20):
    G.add_edge(i + 40, random.randint(1, 30))
    G.add_edge(i + 40, random.randint(1, 30))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=4321)
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, node_size=30, node_color='red')
```

[image]

**Enlarged k value**

```
import networkx as nx
import random
random.seed(1234)
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(30, 0.4, seed=1337)
for i in range(20):
    G.add_edge(i + 40, random.randint(1, 30))
    G.add_edge(i + 40, random.randint(1, 30))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=4321, k=2)
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, node_size=30, node_color='red')
```

[image]

It is less readable if you need analyse edges with high precision, but it is better if you are care more about nodes.