# Python Networkx Label Legibility Issue - Market Basket Analysis

Tags: python, networkx, market-basket-analysis

I'm trying to make the labels of my networkx circular graph (in python) more legible. Below is the current state of my code and visual. 
I'm trying to better visualize the relationships I've identified in the Market Basket Analysis I conducted.

Is there a way to make the labels more legible, or would you recommend a different method to visualize the data altogether? Thanks!

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df4, 'antecedents', 'consequents')
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_size=100, node_color="skyblue", pos=nx.circular_layout(G))

plt.figure(figsize=(50,50))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to analyze your graph, but looks like circular layout is not good for it. For example:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(50, 0.05)
nx.draw(G, pos=nx.circular_layout(G), node_size=50)
```

[image]

And spring layout for exactly this graph:

`nx.draw(G, pos=nx.spring_layout(G), node_size=50)`

[image]

Shows a far better visualization.

---

But if you really need circular layout for your graph, you can use some tricks from my another answer:

[How to improve network graph visualization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57603117/11227781)

That will force `matplotlib` to draw the graph on the huge image surface:

```
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40, 40)) 
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(300, 0.02, seed=1337) 
nx.draw(G, node_size=30) 
plt.axis('equal') 
plt.show() 
fig.savefig('waka.svg')
```

Comment: I implemented your code and added labels; the visual is larger/ more dispersed now, but the relationships are distinguishable now. Also, the spring layout seems more appropriate. Thanks for the help + insight!

Comment: I have an additional question to this if you can answer: Is it possible to reduce the line overlap (while using spring layout?) I have 3 large clusters and few smaller ones, and I'm curious if i could keep them from overlapping. Also, is it possible to reduce the line overlap within each cluster (for ex. reduce the amount of line overlap in the large spring layout cluster above)

Comment: You can't avoid edge overlapping if you have rather dense graph, If you have several connected components, you can visualize them separately (follow the link to look at code there). Spring layout is used to minimize overlapping so the graph picture is sub-optimal. If it still looks bad, you should play with edge colors, weight etc.